# iTunes Connect - how to remove a company CONTACT?

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to remove an old contact that is bugging me sitting in the menus. It appears when I click Contact Info for a contract and then look in the menus under "Company Contacts". There is a button to ADD a company contact, but I can't find how to remove one?

Any ideas?

This is what support said:

Information regarding correcting your Senior Management contact on your iOS Paid Applications contract can be found in the iTunes connect FAQ, "How do I edit a contact for my company?"

I digged the FAQ, googled, but couldn't find that specific question.

Comment: Yeah this kind of stuff bugs me a lot! In almost any case when it comes to deleting data you either can't do it or have support do it for you. Apple >.<